# Branch Coverage for different kinds of loops

Tags: testing, code-coverage

I know that if I have an if-statement like so...

```
if (x == y) {
   foobar++;
} else {
   if (x == z) {
     foobar++;
   }
}
```

There would be 4 branches to traverse in order to get 100% branch coverage. 2 from the outer if - else, 1 from the inner if statement and another from if it doesn't go into the inner if statement.

However, for something like this...

```
if (x == y) {
   foobar++;
} else {
   while (x < z) {
     x++;
   }
}
```

Are there still 4 branches needed for 100% branch coverage? That is, does NOT going into the while loop from the else statement count as a separate branch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all: There are no if-loops. It's called an if-statement.

As for your question: Your first example has only 3 branches. The first `if` creates two branches. Inside your `else` two more branches are created but this doesn't add up to 4 as they are child branches of you `else`.

```
  if
 /  \
1   else
     |
     if
    /  \
   2    3
```

For the branch coverage of the `while` loop it gets a little complicated. Theoretically a loop creates a possibly infinte number of branches, as you don't know how often it will or can run. There are several practical approaches to measure the coverage of loops. The most simple one is having two branches. One where the loop block is executed, one where it isn't. In this case you still would have 3 branches in your example. There is also the possibility to consider three branches for a loop: not running, runnning once and running more than once. If you use such a coverage measurement, you would have 4 branches in your second example.

Comment: @Clay No. Branch coverage is technically well-defined term, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage.  You are confusing branch coverage and path coverage (a different, but also very well defined technical term).  It may not make you happy to know that people have defined 100+ types of "coverage", each distinct and offering arguably some kind of advantage over some of the others.  Line coverage is conceptually useful because even managers can understand the definition.  Branch coverage is pretty common in real tools.  Path coverage doesn't exist in many tools (none) that I know.